# Add Dynamically Orderby in firestore api

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created an API in which I will be getting the fields to which I have to orderby like
In first query `[{label: 'BookingId', value: 'bookingId}, {label: 'status', value: 'status}]`

In second query I will be getting like this `[{label: 'userId', value: 'userId}`]

I tried to dynamically add orderBy in my Firestore ref like

```
orderByValues = [
    {label: 'BookingId', value: 'bookingId},
    {label: 'status', value: 'status}
] // it will be coming from client side

const query = firestore.collection("collectionNAme")
orderByValues.forEach(order => {
    query.orderBy(order.value)
})
await query.get()
```

But this above is not bringing orderBy result

How to handle it?

Comment: This very good article about sorting https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-sort-array-of-objects-by-property-javascript/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [`orderBy()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#orderby) method returns a `Query`, you need to re-assign the `query` with each newly added `orderBy`, as follows:

```
let query = firestore.collection("collectionNAme")
orderByValues.forEach(order => {
    query = query.orderBy(order.value)
})
await query.get()
```

Comment: Can we do regrex exp type matching in .where clause